# How to concat string to result of .AsConfig in helm?

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I have config like this:

```
{{- with .Files.Glob "files/my-files/*.json" }}
{{ .AsConfig | indent 2 }}
{{- end }}
```

In the end of each file I want to add "FIHISHED!"

How can I achieve it in helm ?

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes?

Comment: @icza I would say - for educational purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.AsConfig`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) method renders and returns all files as a single YAML text. So you can't format the result.

If you want to list all files (with content), separated with an arbitrary text, I suggest to do this "yourself". `Files` is a map of files, mapping from string name to `[]byte` content.

```
{{- with .Files.Glob "files/my-files/*.json" }}
{{ range $name, $content := . -}}
    {{ printf "-%s:\n%s\nFINISHED!" $name $content | indent 2 }}:
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```